# Filtering fetched array in render React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, fetch

New to React here so please bear with me. I fetched a list of data from a server and that I put in the `State` though the `componentDidMount` function. In it, I push the data to my State array named `solo`. It works great until I try to render the array. I need to filter my array to map the data based on one property (`categ`) matching a property from another array, and create buttons in the right category. When I run my code, I only get one button rendered, whichever is first in my `solo` array, in which all my data appears. I'm sure it has someting to do with the asynchronous nature of `fetch`, but I don't understand what.
Here's my code :

```
    componentDidMount(){
      // Get URLS from config
      const data = this.props.config.layerUrls
      // Init state values
      let categ = [...this.state.categ]
      let solo = [...this.state.solo]
      // Loop through categories
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let donneesCateg = data[i]
        let listURLS = donneesCateg["urls"]
        categ.push({['categ']: donneesCateg["name"], ['type']: "categ", ['urls']: listURLS })
        this.setState({ categ : categ })
  
       // Loop through individual URL data
        for (let a = 0; a < listURLS.length; a++) {
          fetch(listURLS[a] + "?f=pjson")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
     // Push to state array
              solo.push({['categ']: donneesCateg["name"], ["type"]: "solo", ["couche"]: data.name, ["url"]: listURLS[a] })
              this.setState({ solo : solo })

            })
        }
      }
    }

render() {
    {
      return (
          <p className="shadow-lg m-3 p-1 bg-white rounded">
            {this.state.categ.length!=0 ? this.state.categ.map(item => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <button id={item.categ} className="categ" value={item.urls} onClick={this.selectChangeMultiple}>{item.categ}</button>
                  {this.state.solo.length!=0 ? this.state.solo.filter(solo => solo.categ == item.categ).map(data =>
                    <button id={data.categ} className="btn" value={data.url} onClick={this.selectChangeSingle}>{data.couche}</button>
                  ) : <p id="loadingMsg">Solo data Loading...</p>}
                </div>
              )
            }) : <p id="loadingMsg">Categ data Loading...</p>}
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Note : I have to go through this loop system because the URLs I use to fetch the data are in a JSON in which they are stored by categories.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, any subsequent call to `setState({solo: solo})` isn't recognized as an update by React. This happens because `solo` is always the same "object" (although mutated with `push`, but React comparison algorithm doesn't go so far as to compare the new and previous. It just compares the old and new `solo`s with something like `===`.

An obvious fix would be to call `this.setState({ solo : [...solo] })` instead of `this.setState({ solo : solo })`, although it would still may cause too many extra rerenders. But it'd be a good start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved it and didn't cause any extra rerenders.